# husky pre push hook before build

Tags: git, husky

I'd like to implement a husky rule so as to make it run `yarn build` and make sure that what's going to be pushed won't break the app.

I've browsed the web, but still not sure if the following is the correct way to do it?

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "cross-env lint-staged",
      "pre-push": "cross-env lint-staged yarn build"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values assigned to `pre-commit` and `pre-push` should be the commands as if they were being run straight from the command line. In this case `cross-env lint-staged yarn build` will be run as one command before pushing. (Haven't used yarn so I'm not sure if that's right.)

Multiple commands can be chained together as follows:

`"pre-commit": "command1 arg1 arg2 && command2"`